# Absolute value some

Tags: arithmetic

Adding signed numbers involves two different rules, both depending on whether the two numbers being added have the same sign or different signs. After determining whether the numbers are the same or different, you use the absolute values ​​of the numbers in the calculation. >> If the signs are equal: Add the absolute values ​​of the two numbers and let their common sign be the sign of the answer. (+a)+(+b)=+(a+b) and (-a)+(-b)=-(a+b)

> > > If the signs are different: Find the difference between the absolute values ​​of the two numbers (subtract the smallest absolute value from the largest) and let the answer have the sign of the number with the largest absolute value. Assume that |al>|b|.

(a)+(-b)=+(a-b) and (-a)+(+b)= -(a-b)

Absolute value

If a= 8 and b= -15, then:

(8)+(-15)= -7

In this case, they actually reversed the order, but note that it doesn't change the result:

(8) +(-15)=-(15-8)

= -(7) --> -7

(+a)+(-b)=+(a-b) and (-a)+(+b)=-(a-b)

To not have +(8-15) the (a)—-> (8) and the (b)—-> (-15) it is because is more difficult to do the subtraction?

Whenether -(15-8) the (a) reversed is(-15)? Is because it’s  easier to subtract?

That's why it says assuming that |a|>|b|?

Comment: The instructions you posted say "subtract the smallest absolute value from the largest"

Comment: (8) +(-15)=-(15-8) It’s substracting  the largest from the smallest..

Comment: $15$ is certainly larger than $8$, you are subtracting smaller ABSOLUTE value (namely $8$) from largest ABSOLUTE value, namely $15$. Look at $15-8$, you are subtracting $8$ from $15$ , and $8$ is the smaller absolute value.

Comment: But it’s not (a)+(b) like the instructions ,its (b)+(a)..

Comment: I do not follow what you are asking at this point

Comment: Like the statement says it’s (a)+(b)  ——(a+b)= 8) +(-15) correct ? (15-8)=(b+a)? Is this correct?